# How to check reason for a process getting killed in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, process

I have a process that gets killed, but no error message is shown in the terminal, while I run it. Is there a way to see some message, or get that information?

I've tried running syslog like it said in an old answer, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you looked in the systemd journal? (ie. `journalctl`)

Comment: and did you create the process yourself?